# Thread-safe multiple producer questions

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I am facing an interesting problem in real life. I simplified the problem to here:

Design two methods A()and a method B(). Each method can be thought of producing an element atom (A or B). A chemical compound A[N]B[M] requires N of A atoms and M of B atoms.

Before we have N of A atoms and M of B atoms, each call to A() and B() will be blocked. When we reach N of A atoms and M of B atoms, the first N A() calls and first M B() calls will return.  For example, if I make N+2 A() calls and follow by M B() calls, the first N A() calls and all M B() calls will return. There will be 2 A() calls remained being blocked?

How do I solve this problem? I am using Java.

Comment: This sounds like you need to be using the `CountDownLatch` class.  It gives you `countDown()` and `await()` methods.

Comment: It's the opposite of what is needed no? the CountDownLatch will block until its counter reach 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **[BlockingQueues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)**:

```
static class AtomA
{       
}

static class AtomB
{       
}

static class ChemicalCompound
{
    BlockingQueue<AtomA> as = new LinkedBlockingQueue<AtomA>();
    BlockingQueue<AtomB> bs = new LinkedBlockingQueue<AtomB>();

    public ChemicalCompound(int na, int nb)
    {
        while (na-- != 0) as.add(new AtomA());
        while (nb-- != 0) bs.add(new AtomB());
    }

    public AtomA A() throws InterruptedException
    {
        return as.take();
    }

    public AtomB B() throws InterruptedException
    {
        return bs.take();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{       
    final ChemicalCompound cc = new ChemicalCompound(2, 3);

    Thread ta = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    cc.A();
                    System.out.println("Got a A!");
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }           
    });
    ta.start();

    Thread tb = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    cc.B();
                    System.out.println("Got a B!");
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }           
    });
    tb.start();

    ta.join();
    tb.join();

    return;
}
```

The **Thread.sleep** are just there for demonstrating the possible interleaving of threads, but of course "in production" remove them.

Result:

```
Got a A!
Got a B!
Got a A!
Got a B!
Got a B!
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I dont think this works. I need to block first 2 A() calls and first 3 B() calls. But seems like your code returns first 2 A() calls and first 3 B() calls, and the rest of the calls will be blocked.

Comment: You said "*For example, if I make N+2 A() calls and follow by M B() calls, the first N A() calls and all M B() calls will return. There will be 2 A() calls remained being blocked?*" This is exactly what this code does: the two first A and three first B pass, the remaining are blocked. So in this case as mentionned by *Gray* you can use some **CountDownLatch**. What is your real use-case?